# Django - How access the value of an instance in views.py

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-templates

I have this model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title2 = models.CharField( max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(default=timezone.now)
    content2 = models.TextField(default=timezone.now)
    post_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_pics')
    post_image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='post2_pics')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then I have this simple view function that allows me to access each of its field in my HTML:

```
def home(request):


    postings = {
        'listings' : Post.objects.all(),
        
    }
    return render(request, 'front/front.html',  postings)
```

```
{% for listings in listings%}
  <h1>{{listings.content}}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

With this, I'm able to access the `content` field for every instance of that model and display it

My question is how can I access the `content` field in my view function and change it. The `content` field holds a zipcode and I want to use an API to display the city of that zipcode(which I already know how to do) and pass it back to the `h1` tag. Each instance holds a unique zipcode so I need it to apply for each instance. How would I approach this?

Comment: You shouldn't use the same name for the iteration variable and the variable iterated over. Try `{% for listing in listings%}`

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way would be to create another variable(from views) which finds the city for a corresponding zipcode and send it through the context dictionary to the template.
**OR**
Add a model city setting default and Null and later based on the entered pincode you can set value to the city attribute of the model..

If you want to edit the value of the CONTENT to the city name ... then ,

The best way would be to override the save method and set the value there,

**models.py :**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.content = API_VALUE_OF_city_name
       super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

if you want to update it from views,

**in views.py :**

```
instance_update = Post.objects.filter(id = <pk of Post>).update(content = NEWLY FOUND CITY NAME)
```